# How to create a backdrop for a dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a dialog:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <div id="start_conditions_scroll">
        <p>Conditions</p>
        My Conditions
    </div>
    <button id="close" class="button" onclick="dialog()">Close</button>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#dialog {
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    showStart();

    document.querySelector("#show").onclick = function () {
        dialog();
    };

    document.querySelector("#show_2").onclick = function () {
        dialog();
    };
});

function dialog() {
    element = document.getElementById("dialog");
    element.style.visibility = (element.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

How can I create a backdrop for that dialog? I want to create something like an overlay over the background.

Comment: Your button is a child div of the "dialog" div. Have you tried adding a background to that div, in your .css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap your `#dialog` div in a container div you could do something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="dialog-container">
    <div id="dialog">
        <div id="start_conditions_scroll">
            <p>Conditions</p>My Conditions</div>
        <button id="close" class="button" onclick="dialog()">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#dialog-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#dialog-container:before {
    content:"";
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
#dialog {
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;

}
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86zdnahp/1/) for a demo.

The `#dialog-container:before` is creating you backdrop in this demo.

Answer (score 6):

## Use `<dialog>`

It's not yet the preferred solution but consider [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) along with its pseudo-selector `::backdrop` which will do what you're looking for.

Although it's not well supported yet there is this polyfill: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill

Here is a [great article](http://demo.agektmr.com/dialog/) and a pertinent snippet:

> ## Why do we need  element while it's possible using libraries?
>
> Dialogs are such common UI components that it makes sense for the web platform to support them natively. This way you won't need a library just to popup a dialog.
>
> `<dialog>` is also great for accessibility. The browser understands what element is a dialog and whether it's modal, so accessibility technology like screen readers can know which content should be non-interactive.
>
> Also, modal dialogs are pushed on a well-ordered stack called the "top layer", rendered above all other elements, regardless of their z-index. Relying on z-index to put your modal dialog on top can be brittle in a complex web page. For example, the dialog may be stuck inside a low level stacking context, or other components may also try to be on top, or dynamic style changes may occur.

```js
var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog')

document.querySelector('#show').onclick = function() {
  dialog.showModal();
};
document.querySelector('#close').onclick = function() {
  dialog.close();
};
```

```css
dialog::backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
dialog {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button id="show">Show</button>
<dialog>
  <div>All your stuff</div>
  <button id="close">Close</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: i used dialog before but it is not supported by IE, Safari and Firefox. So i cant use it.

Comment: Did you try the polyfill? Github tells me it "works on modern versions of all major browsers. It also supports IE9 and above."

Comment: currently, this is only available to ~75% of users: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_backdrop_dialog

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to use the HTML `dialog` element [: The Dialog element][1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

```
<dialog>
  <button autofocus>Close</button>
  <p>This modal dialog has a groovy backdrop!</p>
</dialog>
<button>Show the dialog</button>
<style>
    dialog::backdrop {
        background-color: rgba(150, 100, 200, 0.5);
    }
</style>
```